# Hope std::string::operator[] could return unsigned char

Tags: c++, string

if `s` is of type `string` in C++,  `s[n]` will return a `char`, not `unsigned char`.  This creates lots of problem for me since I have to do type conversion everywhere.

The following code will not print "yes".

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

typedef unsigned long ulong;
typedef unsigned int uint;
typedef unsigned short uint16;
typedef unsigned char uchar;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    string s = "h\x8fllo world";
    printf("%d\n", s[1]);
    if (s[1] == 0x8f) {
        printf("yes\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I can make it work by changing the above to be `if ((uchar*)(s[1] == 0x8f) {`, but there are too many occurrences.  I really hoped that the `[]` operator on `string` class could return a `unsigned char`!!  Is there a way to do this?

Comment: (1) look at the cstdint header which has `std::uint16_t` and similar.  (2) use a `std::vector<unsigned char>` ?

Comment: _"This creates lots of problem for me since I have to do type conversion everywhere."_ Didn't you create the problem for yourself when you decided to use `unsigned char` "everywhere"? What was your reason for that?

Comment: `if ((uchar*)(s[1] == 0x8f)` is not what you meant to write, is it?

Comment: More about `char` signedness: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17097537/why-is-char-signed-by-default-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `std::string` is `std::basic_string<char, ...>`, and there's nothing you can or should do to change that.

You could force your implementation's `char` to be unsigned ([some compilers allow this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0d294k5z.aspx)) and stick assertions everywhere to prevent your code from compiling with a signed `char` type.

You could switch to `std::basic_string<unsigned char, ...>` or even `std::vector<unsigned char>`.

But, personally, I'd just compare the character against another character (instead of an integer):

```
if (s[1] == '\x8f')
```

#### ([live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dac384fc89d5958c))

I think this is better code anyway.

Comment: Comparing to a `char` constant rather than an `int` constant seems like the obviously right thing to do.

Comment: Thanks @lightness-races-in-orbit.  Should have thought of it.  The trick of using `'\x8f'` is nice!

Comment: @codingFun: I wouldn't call it a "trick"; it is the default, obvious thing to do in the first place! :) (As Hurkyl said)

Comment: @codingFun: I suggest dropping that habit if you want people to understand you properly. :)

Comment: Will do. Thanks @lightness-races-in-orbit.

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to use a `std::basic_string<unsigned char>` (`std::string` is really just a `typedef` to `std::basic_string<char>`). That will mean modifying your code to use your new `typedef` instead of `std::string`, though that should be a fairly simple search-and-replace refactoring.

See [Strings of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294746/strings-of-unsigned-chars) for more details.

Comment: Thanks @Trebor_Rude.  Like your answer too.