# Unsigned string construction impossible

Tags: c++, string, char

I was looking for a way to get a string of unsigned chars.
So I stumbled upon this [Strings of unsigned chars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294746/strings-of-unsigned-chars)

So the answer is to create a new typedef as follows :

```
typedef std::basic_string<unsigned char> ustring;
```

The thing is, I'm not able to construct with this. when I try :

```
char *p = "123123";
auto s = ustring(p);
```

I get the following error :

```
no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, 
_Alloc>::basic_string [with _Elem=unsigned char, 
_Traits=std::char_traits<unsigned char>, _Alloc=std::allocator<unsigned 
char>]" matches the argument list
```

Can someone please shed some light on this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Would be a nice question if you dropped the C tag, and replaced your image with inline text.

Comment: Thank you, now it's a nice question. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Irrespective of whether or not `char` is `signed` or `unsigned` on your platform, `char`, `unsigned char`, and `signed char` are **all distinct types**. Rather like `int` and `long` are distinct types even if they have the same number of bits and complement scheme.

So you'd have better luck with

```
const unsigned char* p = (const unsigned char*)"123123";
```

where I've inserted `const` qualification to emphasise the *read-only* nature of the `const char[7]` literal.

Comment: Silly me! Thank you!
I think I need a cast for p : 
unsigned char* p = (unsigned char*)"123123";

Comment: Oops. Yes indeed you would. We'll publish jointly!